# Show row names and dendrogram in similar side using heatmap()

Tags: r, heatmap

I am drawing a heatmap of differentially  expressed genes in **R** using `heatmap()` function.

I want to show my 88 row names at the side that I am showing my clustering/dendrogram (left side). They are now on the opposite sides.

in `Heatmap()`, it could be done using `row_names_side = "left"` and `row_hclust_side = "left"`, **BUT** I want its option in `heatmap()`.

This is the script I am using:

```
heatmap(as.matrix(data.prop), Rowv = as.dendrogram(row.clus), Colv = NA, col = scaleyellowred, margins = c(10, 3))
```

Comment: NOTE: I have the same issue in pheatmap().

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Dear zx8754, Hi and Thanks. I did not get the point.

Comment: Please provide reproducible data, on R console type `dput(data.prop)`, and copy paste the output to this post. So we have a data to make plots, so that we can reproduce the same "problems". The `data.prop` doesn't have to be your real data, it can be dummy data as long as it is representative of the real data.